# 2 sums in SQL not adding up total spend by product

Tags: sql, sum

I have the following query which is working OK to give me the product code, name, qty sold but I now want to show the total spend which is the sum of the ORDER_LINE_NETT_TOTAL.

This is the query so far all working apart from the TOTAL_SPEND by Product code as well.

```
SELECT
Sum(dbo.ODBC_ORDER_LINE_ALL.ORDER_LINE_QUANTITY) AS UNITS_SOLD,
Sum(dbo.ODBC_ORDER_LINE_ALL.ORDER_LINE_NETT_PRICE) AS TOTAL_SPEND,
dbo.ODBC_ORDER_LINE_ALL.ORDER_LINE_PRODUCT_CODE,
dbo.ODBC_ORDER_LINE_ALL.ORDER_LINE_PRODUCT_NAME,
dbo.ODBC_ORDER_LINE_ALL.ORDER_LINE_UNIT_COST
FROM
dbo.ODBC_ORDER_ALL
INNER JOIN dbo.ODBC_ORDER_LINE_ALL ON dbo.ODBC_ORDER_ALL.ORDER_ID = dbo.ODBC_ORDER_LINE_ALL.ORDER_LINE_ORDER_ID
WHERE
dbo.ODBC_ORDER_ALL.ORDER_ACCOUNT_ID = 436050 AND
dbo.ODBC_ORDER_LINE_ALL.ORDER_LINE_INVOICE_DATE >= '2011-09-01 00:00:00'
GROUP BY
dbo.ODBC_ORDER_LINE_ALL.ORDER_LINE_PRODUCT_CODE,
dbo.ODBC_ORDER_LINE_ALL.ORDER_LINE_PRODUCT_NAME,
dbo.ODBC_ORDER_LINE_ALL.ORDER_LINE_UNIT_COST
```

Thanks
Roy

Comment: Do you have some example data to show how it's failing?

Comment: You need to elaborate more. Your question doesn't provide enough information about what exactly you want. In fact, it doesn't even ask a question.

Comment: You should provide more infomation when asking a question. Some example data and erroneous output at a minimum. That said, I'd guess that the total spend is the sum of net price * units sold, not just the sum of net price...

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this?

```
select Sum(dbo.ODBC_ORDER_LINE_ALL.ORDER_LINE_QUANTITY *
           dbo.ODBC_ORDER_LINE_ALL.ORDER_LINE_NETT_PRICE) AS Total
```